# React not rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code:

```
var Item = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
                React.createElement('div', {},
                        React.createElement('span', {}, this.props.a),
                        React.createElement('span', {}, this.props.b)
                        )
                );
    }
});

var RParent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {messages: []};
    },
    addMess: function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.state.messages.push({
            a: data.a,
            b: data.b
        });
        this.setState({messages: self.state.messages});
    },
    render: function () {
        var messages = this.state.messages;
        return (
                React.createElement('div', {},
                        React.createElement(Item, messages))
                );
    }
});

var box = ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(RParent), document.getElementById('parentDiv'));

function render(a, b) {
    box.addMess({
        a: a,
        b: b
    });
}
```

Data is sent to the `render` function. It appears that somehow the properties are not reaching the render function of the `Item` as they appear to be `undefined` when I try print them to console.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

The problem is that nothing is rendered into the "parentDiv". It just remains blank. However, on inspecting the elements, I can still see two "span" children under it (which were not created in html or anywhere else except here). But those span elements have no content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a fundamental problem to your code. You are trying to pass 'a' and 'b' to your react component through an external function 'render' that seems to be invoking one of the component's functions. This is wrong.

You should pass 'a' and 'b' to your React component RParent as props. Whenever the value of 'a' and 'b' change, your parent component will automatically rerender.

```
var Item = React.createClass({
render: function () {
    return (
            React.createElement('div', {},
                    React.createElement('span', {}, this.props.a),
                    React.createElement('span', {}, this.props.b)
                    )
            );
}
});

var RParent = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function () {
    return {messages: []};
},
,
render: function () {
    var messages = this.props.messages;
    return (
            React.createElement('div', {},
                    React.createElement(Item, messages))
            );
}
});

ReactDOM.render(
    (<RParent messages= {'a': a, 'b': b} />)
    , document.getElementById('parentDiv'));
```

Comment: `<RParent messages= {'a': a, 'b': b} />` what are a and b that you're assigning to the keys?

Comment: @free-soul I deleted the other answer. a and b are the values, same as in the question. Please see the render function.

Comment: @AmoolyaSKumar Thanks, just a quick question, I haven't tried the code yet (won't be able to for a while) but may I ask where should I be pushing element into `messages` array? In render event? Or `componentWillMount` event? My implementation demands array for the control so I need to have an array too

Comment: Hey, I will need to see your entire code to tell you exactly. Basic rules are : 1: you cannot change a component's props from within a component. (If you want RParent component to push elements into messages array, you should keep it in the state, and not props.) 2: You can change the component's state in any lifecycle method (componentDidReceiveProps or componentDidMount), (but NOT in render method)

Comment: Thanks, that helped!